# How to show HTML content in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

when i am trying to show the HTML content in silverlight using the HtmlHost control it shows me the warning popup.

"The HtmlHost control should always be used with a windowless plugin. It cannot work reliably if this property is not specified"

How i can hide this warning popup

please help,thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the

```
<param name="windowless" value="true" />
```

to the 'yourprojectnameTestPage.html' and add

```
Silverlight.CreateObject(,,,{windowless:'bool'});
```

to silverlight.js

this two solves my problem cheers :) :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, judging by the message you get, I would suggest setting the windowless mode property of your silverlight object to true.

Go to the html or aspx page where the silverlight object is created and add the property:

```
    <div id="silverlightControlHost">
    <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
      <param name="source" value="ClientBin/YourApplication.xap"/>
      <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
      <param name="background" value="white" />
      <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50401.0" />
      <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
      <param name="windowless" value="true" />
      <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.50401.0" style="text-decoration:none">
          <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
      </a>
    </object><iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe></div>
```